# Delete "posts" From Firebase on button click in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the way I store my posts in firebase. I am trying to remove this reference when a button is clicked to delete it. I am having trouble understanding how to access this "posts" node. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a reference to your DB, go to the "posts" child and remove.

```
var ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()

self.ref.child("posts").remove()
```

I'm assuming posts is a direct child of the root reference.

Check the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), they're pretty useful!

Comment: If I create a post by autoId how do I delete only that post?

Comment: I want to be able to only delete the post I click the delete button on

Comment: When you click the delete button, sabe the postId in a variable, then extend the reference: self.ref.child("posts/"+postId).remove()

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming posts is a direct child of the root reference.

```
let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")
        userRef.removeValue { (error, userRef) in
         if error != nil {
             print(error)
             return
         }
       print("Posts Deleted")                    
      }
```

Comment: What if I am saving with autoId, how can I access I will update code above

Comment: I want to be able to only delete the post I click the delete button on